# Kendo line chart notes aren't shown

Tags: kendo-ui, data-visualization, linechart, kendo-dataviz

I use kendo dataviz chart and want to add notes. This is the code I've written

```
   $("#resultChart").kendoChart({
            dataSource: resultsDataSource,
            title: {
                text: "Results"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line"
            },
            series: [{
                field: "Points",
                name: "Points",
                noteTextField: "EventName",
                notes: {
                    label: {
                        position: "outside"
                    },
                    position: "bottom"
                }
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                field: "EventDate",
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
```

Everything is working as needed, i.e. chart is drawn with appropriate data, but notes aren't shown.

Please help me find out why notes aren't shown, if there's data in "EventName" property(I've checked). I want to mention that I am using kendo ui 2013.1.514 version.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have EventName properties inside data with almost a value different to "" or undefined? The notes must be inside your data (resultsDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

In your series definition, you have `noteTextField: "EventName"`, which means you must have the property `EventName` defined for each item in your DataSource, as @ccsakuweb alluded to.

This means that in your DataSource, the data items should look something like this:

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "Result #1", EventName: "Note 1" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "Result #2", EventName: "Note 2" }
];
```

Kendo's documentation about the Notes feature is located at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/notes .